# Sort table with ascending or descending order without a library

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, sorting, dom

This is my first day coding, and I need help with sorting a table in ascending/descending order. The idea is that when a column is clicked it will sort in ascending order, and then it is clicked again it will sort in descending order, then repeat.

This is the function I have created so far.

```
    /*
    * A function to show sort data.
    */
    function sortTable(n) 
    {
      var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
      table = document.getElementById("usersId");
      switching = true;
      dir = "asc"; 
      while (switching) 
      {
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) 
        {
          //start by saying there should be no switching:
          shouldSwitch = false;
          x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[n];
          y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[n];
          if (dir == "asc") 
          {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) 
            {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
            }
          } 
          else if (dir == "desc") 
          {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) 
            {
              shouldSwitch = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) 
        {
          rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
          switching = true;
          //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
          switchcount ++;      
        } 
        else 
        {
          if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
            dir = "desc";
            switching = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is a table example

```
<table id="table">
      <tr>
        <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Number</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Fruit</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Eater</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>JeffVeggies</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Grapes</td>
        <td>MattTreeHugger</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>KevinJuicer</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I have doubts about the `for`-loop within the `while`, but the alternative was nested `for`-loops. What is the correct, optimal way of sorting?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a library or to implement your own sort routine.  [Sorting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is built into arrays.

```
document.getElementById("usersId").rows.sort((a, b) => {
  aInner = a.getElementsByTagName("td")[n].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
  bInner = b.getElementsByTagName("td")[n].innerHTML.toLowerCase();

  return aInner < bInner ? -1 : +(aInner > bInner);
});
```

Note that there may be better ways to do this in Javascript.  For example, you might want to get all your lowercased inner HTML first.  I'm not really a Javascript developer, so I'm not going to try to make the most efficient version (look in the documentation under [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sorting_with_map)).  This will be simpler than yours for small tables and vastly more performant for very unsorted large tables (because it's a loglinear sort rather than a quadratic sort).

Comparison function based on the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17765169/6660678).  Swap `a` and `b` in the first line to reverse the direction (I believe that I have it for ascending here).

```
document.getElementById("usersId").rows.sort((b, a) => {
```

Opposite direction.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I appreciate that. I did not know about the `.sort()`. But now that you have mentioned it, I am seeing more examples for this problem.

I found a stackoverflow thread. Is it a better solution than what you are suggesting?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462632/javascript-sort-table-column-on-click

Answer (score 0):

One gotcha with the string digit comparison is that \$ 1 < 11 < 2\$. To help with that, and a bunch of other gotchas, there is [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) with its `numeric` option. Once the table is sorted by column, clicking on the same column doesn’t need to sort again as it would suffice to just `reverse()` the rows. Semantically, it would be good to markup for the table headers with `<thead>`, to differentiate it from the body `<tbody>`.